# Java Ajax JSON + file separator (path)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, file

I have a servlet which builds a JSON string containing one or more file paths.

String generated by servlet:

```
{"files": "li_digitalized#C:\Users\FABIO~1.HAE\AppData\Local\Temp\fusion_capture\fscan184082140.7785773767018386[610713834376481050].JPEG"}
```

To build the path, Im using java's File.separator, which returns "\" on Windows.

To call the servlet, Im using JQuery's $.ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: Scan.baseURL + 'twainServlet/?action=groupFiles',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
            success: function(data)
            {...},
            error: function(data)
            {
              alert(xhr.status);
         alert(thrownError);
            }
});
```

After the servlet is called, I receive this error:

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token U
```

I pasted my JSON String in this website: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/
and I found out that all the file separators "\" are replaced by nothing, so my path becomes

```
files :"li_digitalized#C:UsersFABIO~1.HAEAppDataLocalTempusion_capturescan184082140.7785773767018386[610713834376481050].JPEG"
```

Is there a way to fix this without having to replace all the file separators on the server side?
If i do that, my string works... but I dont want to do that.
What causes this problem?
Any smart solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

\ is the escape character.  Either switch to / character in your path or use \\.

Comment: I actually encountered the exact same problem while writing this answer.  #irony